# Is embedding a link to a PHP program in a CSS file safe?

Tags: php, css, security

While working on a website I inherited, I was trying to find a background image loaded by the page because it's not stored in the media manager or in the theme's image directory.  When I used Chrome's browser inspector to try and download the image, Chrome downloaded a PHP program instead.  So, I took a closer look at the CSS file I was inspecting, and found this:

`section#headerimg{height:600px;position:relative;z-index:-1;background:url(../images/headers/rotate.php) no-repeat 0 0;background-size:cover;/* Article`

Being that this makes it easy to download the PHP source file that calls the image to be displayed rather than the output (the background image), is this a safe thing to do in a CSS file?  Is it even valid CSS?  Note that this is not a PHP file that generates the CSS file, it's a static CSS file.

Comment: what do you mean, "safe"? hackable? it's just a url. a url can point at ANYTHING on the web, regardless of it whether it's a php script, an image, or a css file, or even someone running the infinite monkeys protocol.

Comment: `Being that this makes it easy to download the PHP source file that calls the image to be displayed rather than the output` Huh? That's not how servers work.

Comment: And, neither CSS nor your browser cares that the image URL happens to end in `.php`.

Comment: Open the PHP file and locate at what it does. The `rotate` name to me suggests it displays different randomly, based on location, or on some frequency. If you are getting the PHP source your server is misconfigured.

Comment: chris85... "If you are getting the PHP source your server is misconfigured"... thanks, that appears to be the issue.  I just tried to replicate it again, and I found I can only pull down the php script using Chrome on a Mac.  Chrome on Windows displays the image as expected.  I'll pass this on to my client's hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

chris85 is correct.  It turns out my client's hosting provider did not have the permissions set right on my client's account.  I contacted the hosting provider and they corrected the issue.  Now the referenced PHP file executes as it should.  Thank you for your help.